# Get instance initialized with the new App Startup API

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack

I saw this new API in the Android dev guide,and I wanted to try it out since it looked like a really nice way to initialize components. But looking over the articles and the examples, it makes no sense to me how am I suppose to use this API. I get the first example, in order to use the `WorkManager` you would first need to call its `initialize` method, so this new API can handle that for you. But the `create` method of the `Initializer` returns an instance of whatever you are trying to initialize. This means that that instance is somewhere available for you to grab. But there is no explanation on how to retrieve that instance later in your code to use it.

So my question is if there was anyone who got around to test this new API, if you could give me an example of how you use the instance that the App Startup API initialized for you. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of now, the library leaves this up to the developer. The point is mainly to add a unified way for libraries to automatically initialize themselves without boilerplate code.
If you are the author of a library using this approach, you are still obligated to provide a way of obtaining these objects.

### Edit

I went with the assumption that `AppInitializer.getInstance(context).initializeComponent(...)` is only used for creating new instances.
However, after having a look at the source code, it turns out instances are cached and immediately returned here if they have been inititialized earlier.
But on the down side, you will need to pass a Context object.

I would also advice to only call it from the main thread, since there is no singleton-style locking in place

Comment: Oh,ok. Looking at the second example in the article I thought the API also provides a way of obtaining the instance since that ExampleLogger gets intialized using a constructor thus only that particular instance gets intialized (unless the constructor assigns to a static field)

Comment: Oh,so you actually need to call the initialization manually in order  to get the result. Thx!

Comment: if you set everthing up as explained here https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup#manifest-entries
initialization will happen automatically at app launch, calling initializeComponent again will always return the same instance. The phrasing is a bit vague

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But,if i understand correctly, unless you call initializeComponent manually, then you need your component to also have a way for you to retrieve an instance,

Comment: Is demo app present anywhere in JAVA or Kotlin?

Comment: How to handle rest call in component to initialise?